# How can I fit either height or width based on aspect ratio in HTML CSS JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, center

I have been searching for an answer for quite a while now and it seems that I just can't find the right question to ask.

I have an image that has the dimensions 1024x768, so that means the aspect ratio is 4:3.

I would like to position this image to be in the center of the screen and to take either the full width or height, so all the image can be seen on any aspect ratio or any size of browser window.

I attach a [sketch](http://tinypic.com/r/167l3zm/8) in order to explain what I want to achieve. On Screen 1 there is a wide screen and the image should fit the window's height and horizontally centered, while on the second screen there is a portrait (or anything that is not wider than 4:3) view, in this case it should be vertically centered and fit the parent's width.

---

Right now I have, let's say, a myImg class on this image

`.myImg { width: 100%; height: auto; }`

The problem with this approach is that it always fits the width and if the screen's (or window's) aspect ratio is wider than 4:3 (for example 16:9) some of the image will not be displayed on the screen.

In the solution I'd prefer pure CSS, but if necessary some (Vanilla) JS is ok, too.

Answer (score 2):

Add this to your .myImg Class and set the image as a background image on a div or similar:

```
background-size: cover;
```

Answer (score 0):

change .myimg to

```
.myimg
{
    position: absolute;
    max-width: 100%;
    top: 10%;
    left: 10%;
}

.myimg:empty
{
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -o-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

and add at the top of your css to make it responsive

```
@media screen and (orientation: portrait) {
  .myimg { max-width: 100%; }
}

@media screen and (orientation: landscape) {
  .myimg { max-height: 100%; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the `max-width` ([w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_max-width.asp)) and `max-height` ([w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_max-height.asp)) CSS properties. Try settings them to viewport values like so:

```
img {
    max-width: 100vw;
    max-height: 100vh;
}
```

Here an example snippet:

```css
html, body {
    margin: 0;
}
img {
    max-width: 100vw;
    max-height: 100vh;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<img src="http://aduphoto.com/images/folder-10/snow-nature-hd-pictures-5.jpg" alt="">
```